# How to scale the button to its original aspect ratio?

Tags: c++, user-interface, cocos2d-x

My application has a resolutionPolicy set to EXACT_FIT so it covers the entire area of the screen producing a stretched UI. There are some buttons which were circular in the original aspect ratio, but now they have become oval in shape. So, I am not able to figure out the scaling factor I need to use to make them circular again.

To make them circular on every resolution, I would need an appropriate scaling factor according to the width and height of the screen, but I am not able to figure it out exactly.

```
std::string buttonNormalIcon = "menu/back.png";
    std::string buttonPressedIcon = buttonNormalIcon;
    cocos2d::ui::Button* button = ui::Button::create();
    std::string buttonDisabledIcon = buttonNormalIcon;
    if(buttonDisabledIcon.find(".png") != std::string::npos) {
        buttonDisabledIcon = buttonDisabledIcon.insert(buttonDisabledIcon.find(".png"), "_disabled");
    }

// This is the part which needs to be figured out.
float scalingFactor = 1.0;
backButton->setScale(scalingFactor);
```

I thought to scale according to X and Y axis too.

The buttons should be circular in the final app.

Comment: for button, keep either scaleX or scaleY 1.0 and adjust another. For example scaleX = 1.0, scaleY = stretchAspectRatio.

Answer (score 0):

Since your use-case requires you to scale buttons based on the width and height of the screen, you can write code similar to what follows:

```
const Size& screenSize = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();

//define a CONST_1 float variable and an appropriate scale CONST_1_SCALE
if ((screenSize.width / screenSize.height) > CONST_1) { 
    backButton->setScale(CONST_1_SCALE);
} else if ((screenSize.width / screenSize.height) > CONST_2) { 
    backButton->setScale(CONST_2_SCALE);
} else {
   //write code to scale the button based on other ratios 
   ...........
}
```

Based on the above logic, you can scale your button dynamically as needed.